# Ubuntu 19.04 randomly has some apps become unresponsive

Tags: 19.04

First week diving full in and replacing windows 10 with Ubuntu 19.04. Actually really enjoying it, but it seems randomly unresponsive at times?

Namely Chrome and Steam will suddenly lock up. And need to be restarted to work again. The worst offender though is the snap store. Snap store downloads seem to get stuck at 99% for several minutes. Many times to even start an install I will have to spam-click the install button. I'm not running any intensive programs when these hiccups happen and I believe I'm up-to-date on updates.

This is a pretty clean install so I'm assuming it's either an issue with Ubuntu itself or my hardware. I also checked enable to download 3rd party drivers on install. Only other thing I could think of is I have almost no space left on my SSD.
I'm running:
i5 4680k 3.5 GHz, 24 gb DDR3, Crucial 128gb ssd, EVGA GTX 970 4GB

Comment: are you using snapped chrome and steam?